# Why isn't Word adding spaces between differently styled paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, line-spacing

I have two differently styled paragraphs in Microsoft Word 2010. The first paragraph uses the ***Subtle Emphasis*** style, while the second uses ***List Paragraph***. The paragraphs are each separated by 10pt spacing.

[image: Two differently styled paragraphs with spacing]

I highlight my text, select **Paragraph**, check ***Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style***, and press **OK**.

[image: Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style]

For some reason Word must think ***Subtle Emphasis*** and ***List Paragraph*** are the same style, because checking this option removes the spacing between my two opening paragraphs.

[image: Two differently styled paragraphs without spacing]

**Why isn't Microsoft Word adding space between two paragraphs which use different font styles?**

Comment: "Subtle Emphasis" is a character style and as such doesn't have paragraph related attributes like spacing before or after. "List Paragraph" however is a paragraph style so it has these attributes. When you select your emphasized text and apply paragraph related attributes, what matters is the actual paragraph style of that paragraph. The Subtle Emphasis character style doesn't play a part when deciding the amount of spacing between those two paragraphs.

Comment: @Atzmon Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subtle Emphasis` is a character style and as such doesn't have paragraph related attributes like spacing before or after. `List Paragraph` however is a paragraph style so it has these attributes.

When you select your emphasized text and apply paragraph related attributes, what matters is the actual paragraph style of that paragraph. The `Subtle Emphasis` character style doesn't play a part when deciding the amount of spacing between those two paragraphs